# Grails set homepage and disable back button

Tags: grails

I have two simple question i couldnt managed to find the answer in the internet. There are:

a) how can i set grails mainpath to, for example, controller "cnt" action "action", instead of index.gsp (im using netbeans)

b) how can i not allow page backward in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) how can i set grails mainpath to, for example, controller "cnt" action "action", instead of index.gsp (im using netbeans)

If you want to change the start page you can do this in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/"(controller:"cnt", action:"action")
    }
}
```

> b) how can i not allow page backward in my website?

impossible